# I've tried to crawl error-codes from the google colab by using python. But it hasn't worked

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, syntax-error, google-colaboratory

First of all, I'm very novice coder.

Sorry about that.

Anyway, I've tried to crawl the error code from google colab's html.

I used python3.7 and BeautifulSoup.

But it doesn't work.

This is my colab address
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Y97NiBXAxiLqKFOY86LlmxbJSsF4ZuO

My plan was that crawling the error code from the colab's html, and then saving in the list.

But the print(list) returned empty list(like this []).

I change and change and change my code.

And I've tried to search the tips using google, but I couldn't find any tips.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

colab_url = 'https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Y97NiBXAxiLqKFOY86LlmxbJSsF4ZuO'

html = urlopen(colab_url+".html")

print(html)

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

nameList = bs.findAll('div', {'class': 'pyerr output-id-1 output-error'}) #, {'class': 'pyerr output-id-1 output-error'}
print(nameList)

for name in nameList:
    print(name)
```

code or way or anything can help

Comment: Did you check the url? Your colab notebook is not public.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I changed my link